# Making a git branch based on upstream, not on my ahead-of-upstream fork

Tags: git, github

I have a fork, which I update from the upstream repo on GitHub fairly regularly.  I use this in my project, so it naturally has all the branches I've created merged in so that I can make use of the fixes I need.

However, the original repo does not necessarily take my pull requests right away.  So, when I want to make a new pull request, without including the outstanding PRs, how can I fork the original repo again to make changes based on it, rather than my fork, so I can submit new, unrelated PRs?

Currently what I've been doing is making a branch of my fork, then rebasing it back to before the oldest outstanding PR, then picking everything besides the outstanding PRs.  This is fine on a small scale, but now that there are some outstanding PRs several weeks and hundreds of commits ago, it's quite a pain, just to submit a small change to upstream.

IOW I want a branch based on the current upstream, not on my current fork, which is ahead of upstream.  How can I get this easily in GitHub?

Comment: I'd keep `master` purely sync'd with the upstream; `my-master` as a container for all the fixes; and a set of `my-fix-xxx` branches for every PR. Does it look complicated? I don't think so.

Comment: Of course, the branches require maintaining. It's probably inevitable, just a matter of keeping things as clear as possible - a branch for a single PR, a PR for a single feature/fix.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I had trouble seeing it in the moment.  I had considered @RuslanOsmanov's answer already, but couldn't see how to get there from my current situation.  I guess I should have done things differently from the start, and for that situation, there's always...rebase!  So I do one last rebase, this time on my fork, and after that keep my own branch with my combined PRs, and leave the fork to just pull from upstream.

This is a bit less than intuitive to me, thinking in terms of how "real" forks would contribute back to upstream, but if that's the only way to do it, so be it.

However, trying to rebase this way gave me the obscure error `Unrecoverable error: Merge commit parent missing` in TortoiseGit.  In this case, the fix was skipping the commit in question, which was just a "catch up" merge anyway; oddly some other catch up merges did not cause problems.

Actually much easier than rebase was a reset HEAD to an old revision, then making a reverse PR to catch up.  From there I was ready with a not-ahead-of-upstream fork.